# My image swap in jquery 1.9 is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
  $(".imgSwap").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).src("_off").replaceWith("_on");
  }).mouseleave(function() {
     $(this).src("_on").replaceWith("_off");
  });
});
```

And this html:

```
<div id="nav">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdleft">
      <img src="../../nav/prev_off.png" width="104" height="37" /></td>
      <td class="tdcenter">
        <img src="../../nav/crumb_on.png" width="30" height="30" alt="Pagina 1" />
         <img src="../../nav/crumb_off.png" width="30" height="30" />
      <img src="../../nav/crumb_off.png" width="30" height="30" /></td>
      <td class="tdright">
      <a href="p02.html"><img class="imgSwap" src="../../nav/next_off.png" width="104" height="37" /></a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I can not convince my image with class imgSwap to swap on mouseenter or mouseleave. 
I think the problem is in the **replaceWith-part** of the code. 
But I don't know how to fix it, and I couldn't find a clear example (clear to me, at least) on Stack Overflow either.

Comment: image swapping like this is a bit nasty, you should consider sprites or using show and hide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
$(this).src("_off").replaceWith("_on");
```

use

```
this.src =  this.src.replace("_off", "_on");
```

You want to do a replacement in the `src` string while [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) do DOM elements replacements.

You should also probably simplify your code using [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) :

```
$(function(){  
    $(".imgSwap").hover(function() {
        this.src =  this.src.replace("_off", "_on");
    }, function(){
        this.src =  this.src.replace("_on", "_off");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this, but it is still not working. Also, I read hover() should not be used in favour of mouseenter, mouseleave in the new 1.9 version.

Comment: Ok, I tried it again and now it does work. I have no idea why it didn't work at first, but it does now. Thanks! :)